# What can I use to access a custom form from the Default.aspx page? (ASP.NET / C#)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

What I'm trying to do is to save a custom form and after that be able to open it from the default page in for of a button, I have a form to create the custom forms, meaning, that in this page you are meant create a new .aspx page to be accessed through the default page, and i don't know how to create nor save it and I don't also know how to modify or update the default page to be able to access the custom .aspx pages saved.

This is what is meant to be on each created .aspx file (This is an example, this is generated on one of these pages)

```
<div id="MainContent_div1" class="panel"> 
    <div id="Section 1" class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">Example</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h3>Example</h3>
            <p>Sample description</p>
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.kiplinger.com/kipimages/pages/18048.jpg" alt="" height="600" width="900">
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#Section Test1">Test1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#Section Test2">Test2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#Section Test3">Test3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br> 

    <div id="Section Test1" class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading"> Sample Section 1</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h3>Sample Section 1</h3>
            <p>Sample description 2</p>
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.kiplinger.com/kipimages/pages/18048.jpg" alt="" height="600" width="900">
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#Section Sample1">Sample1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#Section Sample2">Sample2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#Section Sample3">Sample3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help, edits or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: I Don't see any updates... Anyway, I was doing some research and i found a way to create new .aspx files, I still can't figure out how to modify the "Default.aspx" page, I'll still do my research and wait for an update.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to save the data from the form you just created and show the saved data on a button click, right?

Comment: Yes, But the data needs to be shown in the Default.aspx page. ps: Thank you for the response!